# Power amplifier SST12LP14-QVCE

Tags: pcb, amplifier, integrated-circuit, schematics, power-amplifier

I was reading about this IC and its applications I looked in the schematic I understood what the pins are except for 2 pins, the detection pins. What are they and what they connect to?

I'm not that great in these things but trying to improve. Thanks in advance.[image: schemaatic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those pins are for power detection.  The Det pin outputs a voltage proportional to power of the RF signal being amplified.

They connect to an external meter, or other control circuitry.

Here is a great resource to learn about this:
[Solving the RF Power-Detection Challenge](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/solving-the-rf-power-detection-challenge)

Answer (score 1):

They're for on-chip power detection.

The [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/75031A.pdf) gives very little information on them and I was unable to find anything else on how to connect them.

**Det_ref** is the reference for the detector, this is probably a bias voltage or it might go to a ground, hard to say without documentation.

**Det** is the detector output, it will most likely be a voltage proportional to the output power. It could be read by an ADC or an analog circuit and maybe used to control the drive level or just give an indication of output power.

They're an end-of-life product but if you really wanted to use them you might try contacting the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

The two pins are both outputs used for measuring power.
**Det** is be used relative to ground for single-ended power measurement or with **Det_ref** for differential power measurement.
**Det_ref** is left unconnected for single-ended measurement.

The images below are from the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/75031A.pdf).
The "O" in the 4th-column below means output.
Figure 8 shows that the differential measurement will be more accurate and so should be used for feedback power control.

[image]

[image]

[image]